# Replace Html from <b> to <strong> with javascript and Remove <font> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i have this type of code all over my code

```
<td><font color="#3586DF"><b><span>1</span></b></font></td>
<td><font color="#3586DF"><b><a href="#"><font color="#3586DF">2</font></a></b></font></td>
```

i want to replace **b** with **strong** and remove **font** tag

Result should be

```
<td><strong><span>1</span></strong></td>
<td><strong><a href="#">2</a></strong></td>
```

how i do this with jquery , javascript or Css

Comment: **DON"T** replace it client side. If your code needs fixing, fix your code. Use find and replace in a decent text editor. If you're using javascript to fix your code files, fine. Send the fixed code to the browser though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use jQuery [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```js
$('font').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).contents()
})

$('b').replaceWith(function() {
  return $('<strong>').append($(this).html())
})

console.log($('table').html())
```

```css
strong,
strong a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font color="#3586DF"><b><span>1</span></b></font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font color="#3586DF"><b><a href="#"><font color="#3586DF">2</font></a></b></font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find b tag inside table using loop and replace it like this.

```js
$('#testtable').find('tr > td > font > b').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($('<strong>' + $(this).html() + '</strong>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='testtable'><tr>
<td><font color="#3586DF"><b><span>1</span></b></font></td>
<td><font color="#3586DF"><b><a href="#"><font color="#3586DF">2</font></a></b></font></td>
</tr></table>
```